# How to access the content of text file by indexing

Tags: python

00:CC:3F:27:A0:F0   *2018-07-13 08:18:03*   -0.384   3.477   8.895  11.493  10.407  -4.000   0.003  -20.816 -15.527 78

After reading a text file using readlines() method I am getting data as like above.
I want to assigin this data into a list and access one by one values by indexing like list[0] = 00:CC:3F:27:A0:F0
list[1] = *2018-07-13 08:18:03*

Comment: Habe you tried the split() function ? You could separate the text by a defined delimiter like “ “

Comment: I have used split (" ") meathod , I could see the same result, my intention is to access values one by one by index

Comment: Don't use `readlines()`. If you `with open('f.txt') as f:` then you can just do `for line in f:`. Also I believe @hakkurishian is suggested that you then do `line.split(' ')`.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to split your data by the spaces.

```
string = '00:CC:3F:27:A0:F0 2018-07-13 08:18:03 -0.384 3.477 8.895 11.493 10.407 
-4.000 0.003 -20.816 -15.527 78'

items = string.split()

for item in items:
    print item
```

Then you could iterate through those items for each thing. The only issue is that the date and time will be separate. But if those data value are in the same place each time, as it looks like they might be, thats easy enough to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use REGEXs to match the text patterns you are looking for, check out [REGEX101](http://regex101.com/) to alter any patterns you may need.

```
import re
text = '00:CC:3F:27:A0:F0 2018-07-13 08:18:03 -0.384 3.477 8.895 11.493 10.407 -4.000 0.003 -20.816 -15.527 78'
mac = []

mac.append(re.match(r'([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})', text).group(0))
mac.append(re.search(r'(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})', text).group(0))
print(mac)
```

Answer (score 0):

is that what you need?

```
my_list = my_string.split()  #my_list == [item0, item1, ...]
for idx,item in enumerate(my_list):
    print(idx,my_list[idx])  #output: 0 item0 ; 1 item1 ; ...
```

Comment: you need `for idx,item in enumerate(my_list):` to get the index **and** the element